Why don't we take into account the change in kinetic energy in the isentropic efficiency?

Steam enters an adiabatic steam turbine at $6\,\text{MPa}$, at $600^\circ\text{C}$, with a velocity of $80\,\text{m}/\text{s}$, then exits at $50\,\text{kPa}$, at a temperature of $100^\circ\text{C}$, at $140\,\text{m}/\text{s}$. The power output is $5\,\text{MW}$. What's the isentropic efficiency?

Now I'm new to thermodynamics and all and I know how I should go about the solution. I can find the mass flow rate, and from there calculate the isentropic efficiency using $(h_1-h_2)/(h_1-h_{2s})$ where $h_1$ is the starting enthalpy that I can get from a table, $h_2$ is the real one, and $h_{2s}$ would be the theoretical one in an isentropic system.
But my question is: Why don't we take into account the change in kinetic energy in the isentropic efficiency formula? And if we were to take it into account, would it be the same for both the real work output and the isentropic work output?
$$\frac{h_1-h_2 + 0.5(v_1-v_2)}{h_1-h_{2s} + 0.5(v_1-v_2)}$$
so $v_1$ and $v_2$, would they be the same as $v_{1s}$ and $v_{2s}$? I know $v_1$ would, but $v_2$ as well? Or would the speed change, perhaps in the isentropic case?

For steam turbines the change in kinetic energy is generally considered negligible compared to the enthalpy change

Ah ok thanks, but if it wasn't considered negligible would we use it in the formula, and if we did would the outlet speed for both of the processes (isentropic and real) be the same?

Whether or not it’s the same would depend on why the turbine isn’t isentropic. For example, mechanical friction could dissipate some of the kinetic energy of the flow

Thanks mr Bob, I understand it
